# How to apply regex after applying lookarounds?

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have txt files which has data something like this:

 file 1

```
var field = "123456";
```

file 2

```
var field = abdxg@% "345789";
```

So I used regex expression:

```
(?<=var fhID).*(?=;)
```

This returns: `= "123456"` in file 1 and `= abdxg@% "345789"` in file 2.

Now, I would like a single regex expression that would be able to extract only digits from the string after matching with lookarounds, i.e after modifying my current regex expression I should get `123456` in file 1 and `345789` in file 2.

Comment: Your current regex won't match anything. Is that a typo? Anyway, you could use `(?<=var field).*\"(\d+)\"(?=;)` and find your digits in group 1. In which case, you might get rid of the Lookarounds altogether: `var field.*\"(\d+)\";`.

Comment: Yeah that was a typo, my bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this regex and get matching digits in a capture group:

```sh
(?<=var field)[^;\d]*(\d+)[^;]*(?=;)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/j5OkMq/1)

btw it should be `field` in lookbehind instead of `fhID`.

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?<=var field)`: Lookbehind to assert that we have `var field` before the current position
- `[^;\d]*`: Match 0 or more of any characters that are not `;` and digit
- `(\d+)`: Match 1+ digits in capture group #1
- `[^;]*`: Match 0 or more of any characters that is not `;`
- `(?=;)`: Positive lookahead to assert that we have a `;` ahead of the current position

Comment: There was a typo, my bad and thanks for the explanation